# Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function in hammer.js in chrome browser

Tags: hammer.js

I have been using the hammer.js and jquery.hammer.js. In hammer.js i'm getting the addEventListesener error that is in chrome browser.

And the version which i'm using is 1.0.6, both hammer.js and jquery.hammer.js.

If any one faced this kind of error, please let us know it.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and after some research I figured it out. You need to download the jquery plugin from hammers GitHub.(https://github.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js)

If your using it for a swipe feature you code should look something like this...

```
$(".element").hammer().on("swiperight", function(){
  //code her
});
```